# WPF binding to user control data grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control which I'm trying to leverage for usage across many instances.  But I can't seem to get the binding to work properly.

The control XAML I have:

```
<UserControl x:Class="EveCommon.WPF.Inventory.EveInventoryGrid"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EveCommon.WPF.Inventory"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="uc"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="HeaderRightJustify" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="ColumnRight" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="ItemsDG" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Inventory, ElementName=uc}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- SETUP COLUMNS HERE -->
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class EveInventoryGrid : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty InventoryProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Inventory", 
        typeof(EveInventory),
        typeof(EveInventoryGrid));

    public EveInventory Inventory
    {
        get { return (EveInventory)GetValue(InventoryProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InventoryProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And lastly the calling from the Mainwindow.

```
<inventory:EveInventoryGrid x:Name="ItemsView" Grid.Column="1" Inventory="{Binding Path=Inventory}"  ShowName="True" ShowCost="True"/>
```

Inventory is an instance of EveInventory, and does implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

I just don't see/understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on ` But I can't seem to get the binding to work properly.`? Would be helpful to understand what is not working.

Comment: I can see the main window object instance get populated, but the UI doesn't update with the information.

Comment: Are you calling [`PropertyChanged()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) ? This is something you'll have to do when updating values in UI. Just implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` is not enough.

Comment: So I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and call it on the Main control.  The EveInventory has a property Items which is a List<T> and has a getter/setter which will raise a PropertyChanged when called.  However, it appears the PropertyChanged isn't called when I'm updating the Inventory...

Comment: For Collections take a look at: `ObservableCollection`. When binding to a collection you wanna use `ObservableCollection` instead of a normal `List`

Comment: Ok, changed my List<T> property to ObservableCollection<T> and all is well.  I was leveraging some things from List<T> (like the .ForEach()) but after some minor refactoring all is well.  Thanks

Comment: Yeah the ObservableCollection is missing some functions but you can convert it back to List and then to the stuff you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained above, you'll have to use `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>` when using Bindings with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Otherwise the System will not recognize the change and not update the UI.